# Struggling with prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am unable to get the following working. I want to use prepared statements in the example below, but I am getting an error. The function defnitily gets passed the correct value in $array:

```
  private function getInfoFromSystem($array) {
        try {
            $sql = "
                SELECT     
                    PCO_AGENT.NAME, 
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG.LOGIN AS LOGINID, 
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG.PHONE AS CALLERID, 
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG.STATION AS EXTEN, 
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG.TALKTIME AS CALLLENGTH, 
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG.CHANNELRECORDID AS RECORDINGID, 
                    PCO_SOFTPHONECALLLOG.RDATE, 
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG.RDATE AS INBOUNDDATE
                FROM         
                    PCO_INBOUNDLOG 
                INNER JOIN
                      PCO_LOGINAGENT ON PCO_INBOUNDLOG.LOGIN = PCO_LOGINAGENT.LOGIN 
                INNER JOIN
                      PCO_SOFTPHONECALLLOG ON PCO_INBOUNDLOG.ID = PCO_SOFTPHONECALLLOG.CONTACTID 
                INNER JOIN
                      PCO_AGENT ON PCO_LOGINAGENT.AGENTID = PCO_AGENT.ID
                WHERE
                    LOGINID = :extension
            ";
            $arr = array(":extension" => $array['extension']);
            $query = $this->mssql->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($arr);
           // $sql = "select * from sys.messages where message_id = 229";
            foreach($this->mssql->query($sql) as $row) {

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($row);
                echo "</pre>";
            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Comment: maybe a `var_dump($array['extension'])` too ? :)

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)

Comment: What is your error? What do you expect to get? More important why are you using PDO::query() and not PDOStatement::fetch*() after the call to PDOStatement::execute()?

Comment: Maybe it is only wrong spelling somewhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258715(v=sql.80).aspx : "This error occurs when a column referenced in a Transact-SQL statement was not found in any table specified in the FROM clause of the query."

Comment: http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/svrtsg/@Generic__BookTextView/12578;pt=12560

Comment: on replacing the :extension in the sql with just a numeric value, I am getting the results. Am I doing the prepare() correctly?

Comment: @Mauritz Swanepoel I wrote you a comment, Michael down here wrote you an answer, You are using PDO incorrectly, after a call to PDOStatement::execute() should come a call to PDOStatement::fetch*()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `query()` after `execute()`. Instead [you need to `fetch()` your rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$query = $this->mssql->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($arr);

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($row);
  echo "</pre>";
}

// OR rather than the fetch loop above, use fetchAll()
$rowset = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rowset);
```

In my experience with PDO + MSSQL, attempting to call a regular query immediately after calling `execute()` on a statement that returns rows will fail unless you have called `$query->closeCursor()` first.  However, in this case, you should not be calling `query()` at all.  You've already executed your statement with bound params, and just need to fetch rows from it.